# Using Dropbox in AIR Desktop Application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, dropbox-api

I have been trying to make it work for 2 days but havn't been able to. All I need is to be able to download and upload files. But I can't even establish a connection.  I am using the [following](https://github.com/grossopa/dropbox-as3) API and [here](https://code.google.com/p/dropbox-as3/source/browse/trunk/HsDropboxTest/src/org/hamster/dropbox/test/DropboxClientTest.as) is an implementation example. Can anyone guide on how to establish a connection and starting uploading and downloading files?

I tried to do this:

```
        dropboxConfig = new DropboxConfig(consumerKey, consumerSecret, 
                            requestTokenKey, requestTokenSecret, 
                            accessTokenKey,  accessTokenSecret);            
        dropboxClient = new DropboxClient(dropboxConfig);
        dropboxClient.requestToken();
        dropboxClient.accessToken();
        dropboxClient.accountInfo();

        dropboxClient.fileCreateFolder(ROOT_FOLDER);
        dropboxClient.addEventListener(DropboxEvent.ACCESS_TOKEN_FAULT, onTokenLoadError, false, 0, true);
        dropboxClient.addEventListener(DropboxEvent.ACCESS_TOKEN_RESULT, onTokenLoadSuccess, false, 0, true);
private function onTokenLoadError(evt:DropboxEvent):void
    {
        trace("There was an error accessing token");
    }
    private function onTokenLoadSuccess(evt:DropboxClient):void
    {
        trace("connection established successfuly");
    }
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated because I have to submit my project in a few days and I really want to integrate Dropbox with my app.

Comment: From the documentation in `DropboxClient`: "Register listener before you call any API"

It looks like you're adding the listeners _after_ making your calls to the API.

Comment: The API you are using hasn't been updated for some time ....Dropbox made some changes last year I think so it might be outdated. I suggest you use the official APIs. Maybe go with the PHP one and post your data from Flash to a PHP script that does the uploading/downloading.